# Simplification with squared fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I´m trying to

> Simplify the following fractions $\frac1{(z-\frac d2)^2}-\frac1{(z+\frac d2)^2}$.

And I got the the answer $(z+\frac d2)^2\over(z-\frac d2)^2$$-$$(z-\frac d2)^2\over(z+\frac d2)^2$. But I not sure what I can do with the denominators.

Answer (score 2):

You had made a mistake in rewriting your fractions. Instead of getting:

$(z+\frac d2)^2\over(z-\frac d2)^2$$-$$(z-\frac d2)^2\over(z+\frac d2)^2$

you should have gotten:

$$\frac{(z+\frac d2)^2}{(z-\frac d2)^2(z+\frac d2)^2}-\frac{(z-\frac d2)^2}{(z+\frac d2)^2(z-\frac d2)^2}$$

Then you can join the two fractions together:

$$\frac{(z+\frac d2)^2-(z-\frac d2)^2}{(z+\frac d2)^2(z-\frac d2)^2}$$

The top is now the difference of two squares:

$$\frac{2z\times d}{(z+\frac d2)^2(z-\frac d2)^2}$$

Without knowing exactly how you want to simplify this I'll leave it here as probably the most simplified form.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use $\frac ab+\frac cd=\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$ and $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$

Also $\frac r{\frac st}=\frac{rt}s$ may come handy.